# Angular Material Text-area Placeholder and text alignment issue

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have a `textarea in angular, which is looking as follows:

[image]

In angular, I have:

```
<div *ngIf="whetherDisplay()" class="textarea-text">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
     <textarea matInput name="myTextarea" disabled class="myTextarea" rows="3" 
                      placeholder="This is a placeholder">
         {{ ttsText }}
      </textarea>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

css:

```
.greeting-tts-text {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
}
```

There are two issues here.

1. The `placeholder` which should have been floating above `textarea` is not seen.
2. The starting of the text in the `textarea` ("This is dummy text") is moved to the right side. Why is this so?

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have label in `textarea` for that you need `floatLabel="never"`  like this

```
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never" class="display-block">
        <textarea rows="3" matInput placeholder="Type here..." disabled></textarea>
   </mat-form-field>
```

From Angular Materiel Doc [Float label never](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlbqojxyjyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-label-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the {{}} tags and add a [(ngModel)]="ttsText" inside your textarea tag.
<textarea matInput name="myTextarea" disabled class="myTextarea" rows="3"
placeholder="This is a placeholder" [(ngModel)]="ttsText">